# Django 1.9 send value to view from form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am trying to use a form that will display a drop down list of customers. When the user chooses a customer I want to use the customer name chosen to do some stuff in the same html page. I use the POST method and I get an `Method Not Allowed (POST): /opsform/` error. If I use GET then the URL has the value I choose, but does not trigger the `getCustName` method in my views.py. I have searched enough and tried all recommendations, but not able to get this work. Below are the relevant files. Please help.

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from opsform.models import Customer, Tracking
from django.http.response import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


# Create your views here.
class DetailCustomer(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'customerdrop.html'
    context_object_name = 'customerdrop'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the all the customer information."""
        return Customer.objects.all()

def getCustName(request,cust_name):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=cust_name)

        selected_track =  customer.tracking_set.get(pk=request.GET['cust_name'])

        selected_track.votes += 1
        selected_track.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('opsform:vote', args=(customer.customer_id,)))
```

**Urls.py**

```
  from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name='opsform'
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.DetailCustomer.as_view(), name='customerdrop'),


]
```

**customerdrop.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Choose the customer you are working on</h1>

<form action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if customerdrop %}
<select class="form-control" name="cust_name">
{% for customer in customerdrop %}

  <option value="{{ customer.customer_id }}">{{ customer.customername }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

{% else %}
    <p>No Customer are available.</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `getCustName` method is not called from anywhere in the code you have posted - so how do you expect it to run? Also you cannot arbitrarily POST data to any view - Django has a [Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/) that you should use to do that.

Comment: @solarissmoke thank you. I modified my Url.py  to include   `url(r'^$', views.getCustName,name='getCustName'),` I want the form to redirect to the same page and hence I have `form action=""`. Is that what you meant by method not called? sorry for the naive question.

Comment: But you can't have two views on the same URL. And if you want to run the code in getCustName on submit, you need to have the form action pointing to a URL that routes to that view.